# Fetching data from facebook game application to iPhone application

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have an application where I need to connect to a game app within facebook and fetch data from that app. Say, a user has been playing certain game app in facebook and I need to fetch the points he has scored in that game from my iPhone application. Is it possible ? If so then how to implement it ? Can anyone pls help me out of this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. My arguments:

1. Retrieving game-dependent information for a given user and game seems impossible to me, since that kind of information is usually stored and handled by servers that run that game, not Facebook.
2. Facebook API does not provide such a mechanism. You cannot query such information using FQL on any of its tables. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Good luck.